# Getting onClcik to work in a Shiny App when user clicks on a cell in a table

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a Shiny App and get the `onClick` function to output the cell row/column the user clicked on.

How can I fix the code to display the cell row/column?

Shiny App

```
library(reactable)
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)

iris = iris

ui <- fluidPage(

  reactable::reactableOutput("irisTABLE"),
  textOutput("'cellDATA")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$irisTABLE = renderReactable({
    reactable(iris,
              onClick = JS("
                                function(rowInfo, colInfo) {
                                Shiny.setInputValue('cell_data', colInfo.id + '-' + rowInfo.row.CapRate, { priority: 'event' })
                                }
                               ")
    )
  })

  output$cellDATA = renderText({
    paste0("The cell selected is: ", input$cell_data)
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the`output$cellDATA` to

`if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) { row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-") paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1]) }`

```
library(reactable)
library(shiny)

iris = iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactable::reactableOutput("irisTABLE"),
  textOutput("cellDATA")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$irisTABLE = renderReactable({
    reactable(iris,
              onClick = JS("
                function(rowInfo, colInfo, e) {
                  Shiny.setInputValue('cell_data', colInfo.id + '-' + rowInfo.index)
                }
              ")
    )
  })
  
  output$cellDATA = renderText({
    if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
      row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
      paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: One additional thing, I am trying to print the cell to the console. I try adding: `code`: `      observeEvent(input$cell_data, {
        if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
          row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
          print(paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1]))
        }
      })`

Comment: Okay, this works on this example - just the JavaScript code is not working in my main App.

Comment: Use `print()` like : `observeEvent(input$cell_data, {
      if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
        row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
        print(paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1]))
      }
    })`